# Send attachment in file in sendmail using .sh file

Tags: email, attachment, sh

i wants to send attachment in mail .. i m using this code for send mail 
this is my .sh file  i dont know

```
  cat "/home/ubuntu/source_code/PCC/mail.template" |
 sed s/@SUBJECT@/"$1"/ | 
sed s~@BODY@~"$2"~ | 
sed s/@TOEMAILS@/"$3"/ | 
sed s/@CCEMAILS@/"$4"/ > /home/ubuntu/source_code/PCC/tempMail_"$5".template
    chmod 777 /home/ubuntu/source_code/PCC/tempMail_"$5".template
    cat /home/ubuntu/source_code/PCC/tempMail_"$5".template | 
sed 's/  */ /g' | 
sed 's%><%>\n<%g' | 
sed 's%> <%>\n<%g' > /home/ubuntu/source_code/PCC/tempMail2_"$5".template
    chmod 777 /home/ubuntu/source_code/PCC/tempMail2_"$5".template
   /usr/sbin/sendmail -f "$6" -t < /home/ubuntu/source_code/PCC/tempMail2_"$5".template
    rm -rf /home/ubuntu/source_code/PCC/tempMail2_"$5".template
    rm -rf /home/ubuntu/source_code/PCC/tempMail_"$5".template
```

Comment: There are some many variables here, and sendmail syntax is a minor one. Which MTA are you using? Any logs? You should improve this question, otherwise I guess it'll be downvoted really quick.

Answer (score 1):

Your script should work OK for substituting command line arguments into a form letter template.

Trying to substitute in a "body" sounds odd though.

If you really want to send attachments and not just make substitutions on a form letter, you should use mutt, elm, pine, alpine or some other MUA that will handle MIME attachments instead of trying to use sendmail directly.

Note that sendmail (or whatever work-alike you /usr/sbin/sendmail really is)  may not honor the "-t" flag unless run by root or other "trusted" users.  You don't need the chmod cmds, but they're not contributing to whatever your problem is.

Instead of deleting your temp file, save a copy and examine it to make sure your sed edits are working as intended.